# how to move a directory and it's files to a subtree remote repo

Tags: git, git-subtree

I have a directory in my current repo called **files** that I want to extract to an external repo and then reference in my main project as a subtree. How can I do this without loosing the history of my files in my main repo yet establishing this subtree connection?

main_project.git   <---  files.git

```
root
---data
------files
```

move to

```
root
---remote
------files (subtree)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter` to extract that single folder into a separate repository:

```
   --subdirectory-filter <directory>
       Only look at the history which touches the given subdirectory. The result
       will contain that directory (and only that) as its project root.
```

Afterwards you can use `git submodule` or `git subtree` to include that new repository into your second repository.

Comment: Hi michas, if I understood correctly, this filter-branch will completely remove all history of this subdirectory from my main repo so that I can re-import it as a subtree is this correct? This is not what I want unfortunately because I would like to maintain the history of the files within my main repo even though they will now be part of a subtree in a different location, does this make sense?

Comment: `git filter-branch` will preserve the history. the `subdirectory-filter` will only "remove" everything *outside* the given directory. Just make a fresh clone of your repository and have a look at it for yourself.